# Write all output to file - ofstream C++

Tags: c++, ofstream

Is it possible to write all output to a text file

Expected output (in the text file):

**car**

**bike**

**plane**

Actual output:

**plane**

Code (I tried a for loop) :

```
string vehicle[3]= { "car", "bike", "plane" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {

        ofstream out_file("C:\\Users\\Gadr\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        out_file << vehicle[i] << endl;
        out_file.close();
    }
```

Comment: `ofstream out_file("C:\\Users\\Gadr\\Desktop\\test.txt");` should be outside of the loop. As you have it, it creates a new file every iteration.

Comment: Thanks. great thinking, but that doesn't solve the main problem

Comment: Or if it should really be in the loop, use *"append"* [open mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Comment: @urbanccladr what _"main problem"_?? That's your **main problem** so far,  period. Closing the file inside the loop is wrong as well.

Comment: urbanc, I think you need to better expand on your goal. without more information, what πάνταῥεῖ suggests is where I'd start and what Jarod42 suggests is probably where I'd finish. If you need something weird, you should outline it otherwise you'll get path of least resistance answers.

Answer (score 2):

you should move both openning the stream and closing it to the outside of your loop.

```cpp
string vehicle[3]= { "car", "bike", "plane" };
ofstream out_file("C:\\Users\\Gadr\\Desktop\\test.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{

    out_file << vehicle[i] << endl;
}
out_file.close();
```

Comment: Side note: Most of the time you don't need to bother with manually closing the file. Through the magic of [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/4581301), file streams take care of themselves.